# ¿Cómo puedo hacer este ejercicio en c++?

Tags: c++

“Dados A,By C como números enteros, comparelos e imprimalos de mayor a menor”

Usando solamente if else, como lo hago?

Comment: Por favor considera leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour], tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato pues no muestra avance y/o investigación de tu parte así como dudas puntuales lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: Hola @Jasmine. Acabo de ver que has publicado dos preguntas que salen de un deber escolar. Posíblemente no sepas dónde buscar un manual. Busca **Pensar en C** de *Bruce Eckel* con seguridad encuentras una copia para descarga. Y, con un par de horas de lectura serás la mejor de tu curso.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por el dato del libro, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Te comento que el problema que planteas es muy sencillo te recomiendo que hagas tu mejor esfuerzo por realizar el ejercicio tú mism@.

Igualmente te dejo el aporte por si necesitas apoyo.

Saludos.

```
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main(void) {

     //Declaracion de tus variables enteras

     int A, B, C;

     //Para poder Compararlos Hay que Darles un Valor inicial

     printf("Ingresa A\n");
     scanf("%d",&A);

     printf("Ingresa B\n");
     scanf("%d",&B);

     printf("Ingresa C\n");
     scanf("%d",&C);

     //Comparacion con if anidado

     //1er if
       if (A>B)
      {
//2do if
if(A>C)
{
    //3er if
if (B>C)
{
    printf("C=%i\nB=%i\nA=%i",C, B, A);
}
else
{
    printf("B=%i\nC=%i\nA=%i",B, C, A);
}
//fin 3er if
}
else
{
    printf("B=%i\nA=%i\nC=%i",B, A, C);
}
//fin 2do if


 }
  else
  {

     //2do if Condicion falsa

  if(B>C)
    {
//3er if condicion falsa

if(C>A)
{
    printf("A=%i\nC=%i\nB=%i",A, C, B);
}
else
{
    printf("C=%i\nA=%i\nB=%i",C, A, B);
}
//fin 3er if condicion falsa
      }
   else
      {
     printf("A=%i\nB=%i\nC=%i",A, B, C);
    }
      }
    //fin 1er if

    return 0;
      }
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo pero como identificas la pregunta es mala y de hecho lleva dos votos de cierre, te recomiendo evitar responder a publicaciones así